# Backup storage location

Tags: php, google-cloud-storage, backup-strategies

Plan is to create my own automated backup place for files encrypted with public key, so only I can open them. I don't want to deal with home hardware but regular hosting is too expensive for many GB or even TB.

Hardest question is where to store it: Can I use Google Nearline storage as location as it is extremely cheap per GB? Or is there limitations for such personal use?

Or there is some better / easier solutions without so much coding?

Answer (score 0):

For backups that you aren't going to access very often (i.e. < 1 per month) Nearline is a good choice. The API is the same as cloud storage so it's easy to get working.

Be sure to check out the [docs](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/nearline) and look at the note on throughput as well as make sure the pricing works for you. Make some calculations to find out how long it would take you to restore a backup and how much it would cost to restore a backup.